# Stripe locale setting with custom price and PHP api

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe to collect payments and I am using a price_data element to specify, on the flight, my pricing. here the code

```
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
        'line_items' => [[
            'price_data' => [
                'currency' => 'eur',
                'product_data' => [
                  'name' => 'prenotazione',
                ],
                'unit_amount' => $amount*100,
              ],
              'quantity' => 1,
        ]],
        'mode' => 'payment',
        'payment_intent_data' => [
            'metadata' => ["cart_id"=>$cart_id]
          ],
        'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/mybookings?message=newBkgCreated&cart_id='.$cart_id,
        'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/checkout?message=payment_cancelled&cart_id='.$cart_id,
        'automatic_tax' => [
          'enabled' => true,
        ],
      ]);
    header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
    header("Location: " . $checkout_session->url);
```

How can I specify the locale within this setup?

Thx!

F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Stripe SDK -

> https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/Checkout/Session.php

You would be able set the locale, this way:

```
<?php
    
// Code at the beginning
    
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'line_items' => [
    [
     'quantity' => 1,
      'price_data' => [
        'currency' => 'eur',
        'product_data' => ['name' => 'prenotazione'],
        'unit_amount' => $amount*100,
      ],
    ]
  ],
  'locale' => 'en', // IETF language tag i.e. "en" for English, "es" for Spanish
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'payment_intent_data' => [
    'metadata' => ['cart_id' => $cart_id]
  ],
  'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/mybookings?message=newBkgCreated&cart_id='.$cart_id,
  'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/checkout?message=payment_cancelled&cart_id='.$cart_id,
  'automatic_tax' => ['enabled' => true],
]);

header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
header("Location: " . $checkout_session->url);
```

Hope it helps!